# Interpolating image pixels

Tags: java, image, interpolation

I want to sample a height map for my 3D engine. It might happen that there are more vertices on my terrain than pixels in my image. I created following method:

`public float interpolateFromImage(BufferedImage image, float x, float y){`

This takes the image and the x and y coordinate. The coordinates are given in percent.
My approach was to calculate the distances between the nearby pixels and the given coordinate. This worked fine but I ended up with this:
[image: Output Image; size 1000x1000. Input is a 4x4 picture]

It can be clearly seen that the edges are not as smooth as they should be.

I used following code:

```
    int topLeftX = (int) (x * (image.getWidth()-1));      //index of topLeft pixel
    int topLeftY = (int) (y * (image.getHeight()-1));     //index of topLeft pixel

    float[] distances = new float[4];  
    float total = 0;
    for(int j = topLeftX ; j < topLeftX + 2; j++){           //run through all 4 nearby pixels
        for(int k = topLeftY ; k < topLeftY + 2; k++){
            float dist = (float) Math.sqrt(                    //pythagoras for the distance
                    (x- j/ (float)(image.getWidth()-1)) *
                            (x- j/ (float)(image.getWidth()-1)) +
                            (y- k/ (float)(image.getHeight()-1)) *
                                    (y- k/ (float)(image.getHeight()-1)));
            if(dist < 0.001){
                return new Color(image.getRGB(j,k)).getRed();
            }
            distances[(j-topLeftX) * 2 + (k-topLeftY)] = (1f / image.getWidth()) / (dist * dist);
            total += distances[(j-topLeftX) * 2 + (k-topLeftY)];
        }
    }
    float h = 0;
    for(int j = topLeftX ; j < topLeftX + 2; j++){
        for(int k = topLeftY ; k < topLeftY + 2; k++){
            float p = distances[(j-topLeftX) * 2 + (k-topLeftY)] / total;
            h+= new Color(image.getRGB(j,k)).getRed() * p;
        }
    }
    return h;
```

Does anyone know how I need to change my code ? 
I am very happy for any advice and help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are weighing the colors based in the inverse squared distance from all four corners. The problem here is this: the pixel colors on the edge are affected by the color of the corners across. The pixel colors on the two sides on the edges differ because they are calculated from a different set of four corners.

Solution is to use some common interpolation, like bilinear or bicubic interpolation.

Comment: Mhm yes... I know why it looks like that :) I wanted to use something I did by my own. Seems not to be the best idea. Thank you !:)

Comment: You can always experiment further, thats the best way of learning.